# Replacing random_shuffle with shuffle: How to make a random number generator with a given distribution

Tags: c++, c++17

I am moving from C++11 to C++17 and I have to replace `random_shuffle` with `shuffle`.
But I am facing the following issue:

I need to `shuffle` the contents of a vector using **a random number generator with a particular distribution**.
In my case this is a `std::piecewise_linear_distribution`.

But I don't know how to create a UniformRandomBitGenerator with a given distribution.

I tried ([link to code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8436f95f0f0d22f9))

```
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};


    std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device());

    std::vector<double> i{0.0, 0.1, 1.0};
    std::vector<double> w{0.0, 0.9, 1.0};
    std::piecewise_linear_distribution distr(i.begin(), i.end(), w.begin());

    shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), distr(gen)); // error: 'distr' is not a UniformRandomBitGenerator
```

But `shuffle` requires a generator as a 3rd argument.
How can I make this generator have the distribution I want?

Most examples over the net, like this one, in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_linear_distribution)
present a generator, which feeds a random number into a distribution.

With `random_shuffle` I had to make a function object with the following operator():

```
// random function with desired PDF (and corresponding CDF)
//
struct MyRandomFunc {
  size_t operator() (size_t n)
  {
     double rand_num = rand()/RAND_MAX; // 0 <= rand_num <= 1
     double num = CDF(rand_num); // where 'CDF' = desired cumulative distribution function
     return num * n;    // 'num' is a random number with the desired PDF
  }
};


std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), MyRandomFunc());  // random func with desired pdf
```

Comment: I think that `shuffle` is the issue here. It is not convertible from `random_shuffle`. It should have allowed for a `distribution` parameter also, apart from the `uRNG` parameter.

Comment: Note that the requirements for the uRNG for `random_shuffle` (in C++11) are the same; each value has a equal probability of being returned.

Comment: @MarshallClow, can you point me to the document where this is stated please? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle
Was that also the case 20 years ago, when only `random_shuffle` existed? (That's when I implemented this!)

Comment: I looked it up in a copy of the C++11 standard. [alg.random.shuffle] says "The type UniformRandomNumberGenerator shall meet the requirements of a uniform random number generator (26.5.1.3) type whose return type is convertible to `iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::difference_type`." and (26.5.1.3) says: "A uniform random number generator g of type G is a function object returning unsigned integer values such that each value in the range of possible results has (ideally) equal probability of being returned. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make this generator have the distribution I want?

You don't. `std::shuffle` requires a uniform random bit generator because [it is defined as follows](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/alg.random.shuffle#2):

> Permutes the elements in the range [first, last) such that each possible permutation of those elements **has equal probability of appearance**.

Emphasis added.

What you want is to control the possibility of certain permutations. That's not what `shuffle` is for, so you're going to have to write the shuffling code yourself. Even if you gave it a class that implemented the interface of URBG, the fact that the bits it generates are non-uniform means that the result of calling the function will be undefined. It might do what you want, or it could do something entirely different.

Comment: it is a shame that we `random_shuffle` has been deprecated without a way to produce an equivalent `shuffle` function.

Comment: @GrimFandango: Was `random_shuffle` *guaranteed* to work if the RNG was non-uniform?

Comment: `random_shuffle` simply swaps elements from begining to current iterator. As long as the Random Function generated a number between 0 and the index corresponding to the current iterator, I don't see how that should fail... You can create a shuffle that does not permute the elements "too far from their initial position" if you pass through a non uniform distribution.

Comment: @GrimFandango: You're looking at a specific *implementation*, not [the requirements of the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/depr). This: "Permutes the elements in the range [first,last) such that each possible permutation of those elements has equal probability of appearance." doesn't seem to change anything; the only difference is that the URGB requirement makes explicit an assumption that was previously implicit.